# Calling functions in functions - Python

Tags: python, function

How would I go about to get this to work? I've searched but I can't get it to work still. Should I just put the a() function in the b function even if I add more variables?

```
counter = 1

def a():
    az = 1
    bz = 2
    cz = 3

def b():
    a()
    if counter > 0 :
        print az, bz, cz

b()
```

Comment: The variable in function `a()` is *local* to the function `a()`, can't be accessed in function `b()`.

Comment: This should be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules

Comment: The point is, `a()` is being called correctly in b, but the variables in a don't exist in b.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you need to understand the concept of `scope`. `az`, `bz` and `cz` are known only inside your function `a()`. So you can't print their values inside function `b()`. You could do something like:

```
counter = 1

def a():
    az = 1
    bz = 2
    cz = 3
    if counter > 0 :
        print az, bz, cz

def b():
    a()

b()
```

And as @fileyfood500 said in his comment, you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules).

Answer (score 0):

One potential fix is to return the values from a.

```
counter = 1

def a():
    az = 1
    bz = 2
    cz = 3
    return(az,bz,cz)

def b():
    (az,bz,cz) = a()
    if counter > 0 :
        print az, bz, cz

b()
```